# Pass certificates to AWS MQTT API from in-memory location instead of on-disk

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-iot

I'm setting up an AWS IoT MQTT connection from a Python environment using Python package `awsiotsdk`. I have followed this example https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-python-v2/blob/main/samples/pubsub.py and gotten the demo publish/subscribe to work, so I have all the pieces.

The only difference from the demo is that in my environment the certificates all reside in memory rather than on disk. A hack solution would be to write them to a temp location on disk and follow the example.

I would prefer to simply instantiate the appropriate AWS authentication class which can accept a file-like object rather than a string filename. However following the code only leads me to c-binding dead ends.

How can I create an MQTT client using in-memory certificates?

Comment: Look at `io.StringIO` or `io.BytesIO` - you can write a string or bytes to these (i.e. in-memory) and they appear like a file object.

Comment: Yes, but the `awsiotsdk` doesn't accept file-like objects, it only accept filename strings. Perhaps because it hands off to some C api's under the hood. At least as best as I have been able to tell. I'm new to the SDK so I need correction where correction is due.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I've been able to determine, this is simply not possible. My solution is to use the `tempfile` package to create a temporary directory which I write the cert to and then reference when I create my MQTT client. It's not elegant, but it keeps me from needing to manage the certs as an external dependency (which is what I wanted to avoid).